# How do I make my navbar responsive like flexbox to turn into 2 rows at small breakpoint?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have a nice looking navbar at the bottom of my page with a logo in the center that takes you to the home page, and 2 links on either side that take you to those pages. I have used @media css to make it smaller as the page gets smaller, but once you hit the xs/sm breakpoint, it's just too much to fit onto the screen.

Ex:

|-------Video-------|-------About-------|------LOGO/BRAND------|------Schedule------|--------Ask--------|

Is there any way to make the navbar links stack on top of each other on both sides so I can keep a clean, symmetrical look with the logo in the middle instead of making it a collapsed menu button?

Ex:

|----Video----LOGO/BRAND----Schedule----|

|----About--------------------------------Ask-------|

Comment: Yes. It's possible. Post your code so we can show you how.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on bootstrap v4, maybe you can place another row inside your 1st and 3rd columns, then place two columns inside that new row (one for each link). Use col-sm-12 to force the line to wrap down on small screens, then col-md-6 to let them stack horizontally when you get bigger. It's a lot of nested divs though, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested flex containers and achieve the desired result with minimal code:

```css
.container, .left, .right {
  display:flex;
}

.left, .right {
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.container div, .left div, .right div {
  flex-grow:1;
  text-align:center;
  padding:0px 8px 0px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div>Video</div>
    <div>About</div>
  </div>
  <div class="logo">LOGO/BRAND</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div>Schedule</div>
    <div>Ask</div>
  </div>
</div>
```